# Скрыть от 1 получателя список остальных получателей письма

Tags: php

**Здравствуйте.**

Каким образом можно сделать так, чтобы получатель письма в поле **"кому"** видел свой e-mail, но без списка других e-mail`ов.

**Наработки:**

```
<?php

$from = 'info@mail.ru';//email отправителя 
$to = '<mail1@mail.ru>, <mail2@mail.ru>'; 
$subject = 'Тема'; 
$body= 'Текст письма'; 
$mailheaders = "Content-type:text/html;charset=utf-8\r\n"; 
$mailheaders .= "From: info@mail.ru\r\n"; 
$mailheaders .= "Reply-To: info@mail.ru\r\n"; 
// почтовые заголовки

$mailheaders .= "Bcc: mail1@mail.ru\r\n";
$mailheaders .= "Bcc: mail2@mail.ru\r\n";
mail($to, stripslashes(trim($subject)), stripcslashes($body), $mailheaders);

?>
```

Т.е. чтобы пользователь mail1 не видел мыло mail2 и наоборот.
Конечно, можно сделать $to = ''; и тогда пользователю будет показано "скрытым получателям", но хочется все же, чтобы поле кому было заполнено, и было заполнено корректно.

Comment: самый надежный способ - не хотите, что бы другие адреса были видны - не добавляйте их.
Да, при этом придется рассылать всем по отдельности, но зато надежно и безопасно.

Comment: Солидарен с @KoVadim. В противном случае, при просмотре исходного текста письма можно восстановить кому же оно было отослано.

Comment: Не знаю правильное ли решение, но я придумал пока только форичем письма отправлять.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот, думаю, неплохой для вас способ:

```
<?php

$email1 = array("zozozo@mail.ru");
$listmails = array("zozozo1@mail.ru","zozozo@mail.ru","zozozo2@mail.com");
$ready_email_list = array_diff($listmails,$email1); // здесь список емайлов, отличных 
                                                       от $email1
print_r($ready_email_list); // "[0] => zozozo1@mail.ru [2] => zozozo2@mail.com "

?>
```

Comment: Asen, вы не так меня поняли. Нужно чтобы в поле "кому", в смысле в почтовом клиенте. Т.е. вот открою я на gmail свою почту, открою сообщение, а там в информации о сообщении будет поле "Кому". Я об этом говорил. Но все равно спасибо, может кому и пригодится...

Comment: Угу, не так понял...